# How to store strings as group when I don't know how much group is? (In java)

Tags: java, string

I want to store string as group but I don't know how much group needed. Suppose, As group I have ID, Lecture-1, Lecture-2, .... and more lecture may be added. In 'ID' student ids will be added and their attendance (present or absent) will be added in lectures (suppose lecture-1). How I can do that? Please check data example in picture. [Check data example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9kFgd.jpg)

Comment: If you're seeking for help in stackoverflow, you have to at least show what you've tried. You don't expect people to give solutions when you're yet to do anything.

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

You can represent such structure using a Map>, or Simply Map>, where Integer is the ID and the list of Lecture or String is the group. Is the list contains "Lecture-1" (or an Instance of Lecture) it means it is present.

```
class Lecture {
  private String name;
  (..)
}
```

Comment: Great idea. please, could you say in details?

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution for this would be to create a hashmap that associates the student's ID with a list of booleans where each index of the list represents their attendance of that respective lecture:

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Boolean>> attendanceMap = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Boolean>>();
```

Comment: Wow, great idea. Please could you say in details?

Comment: You can find more info about HashMaps and how to use them here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-hashmap-in-java-with-examples/